# MySQL & C# MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException caught in try catch

Tags: c#, mysql, database

I am getting the following error in my C# code when I press the button. It is caught in my try-catch:

> A first chance exception of type 'MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException' occurred in MySql.Data.dll

I am wondering what it could be that is wrong. Any help is appreciated!

Method:

```
private void addChildBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string firstName = firstNameAdd.Text;
    int ageComboIndex = ageComboAdd.SelectedIndex;
    string age = this.ageComboAdd.Items[ageComboIndex].ToString();

    int genderComboIndex = genderComboAdd.SelectedIndex;
    string gender = this.genderComboAdd.Items[genderComboIndex].ToString();

    string address = addressAdd.Text;

    string caregiverOneName = caregiver1NameAdd.Text;
    string caregiverOnePhone = caregiver1PhoneAdd.Text;
    string caregiverTwoName = caregiver2NameAdd.Text;
    string caregiverTwoPhone = caregiver2PhoneAdd.Text;

    server = "localhost";
    port = "3306";
    database = "childeren";
    uid = "root";
    password = "password";

    MySqlConnection connection2 = new MySqlConnection("Server=" + server + ";" + 
        "Port=" + port + ";" + "Database=" + database + ";" + 
        "Uid=" + uid + ";" + "Password=" + password + ";");

    // Perform databse operations
    try
    {
        connection2.Open();
        string query = "INSERT INTO childdatabase (name2, age, gender, " +
            "adress, caregiver1Name, caregiver1Phone, caregiver2Name, " +      
            "caregiver2Phone) VALUES('" + firstName + "','" + age + 
            "','" + gender + "','" + address + "','" + caregiverOneName + 
            "','" + caregiverOnePhone + "','" + caregiverTwoName + 
            "','" + caregiverTwoPhone + "')";
        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, connection2);

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        connection2.Close();
    }

    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Failed");
        //updateStatus(ex.Message.ToString());
    }

    connection2.Close();
}
```

MySQL CREATE tables set up:

```
create database childeren;
use childeren;
CREATE TABLE childDatabase 
(
    id INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, 
    name2 VARCHAR(50), 
    age VARCHAR(3), 
    gender VARCHAR(6), 
    adress VARCHAR(50), 
    caregiver1Name VARCHAR(50), 
    caregiver1Phone VARCHAR(10), 
    caregiver2Name VARCHAR(50), 
    caregiver2Phone VARCHAR(10)
);
```

Comment: Can you post what your error _actually_ is. Your error message tells us nothing.

Comment: What is inside ex.Message.ToString()?

Comment: @gunr2171 that is the thing, the exception that I stated is the only thing I am shown, thus why I am so confused.

Comment: Have you validated that all your text strings are not longer than their limits?  For example, age string is < 3 characters, gender < 6, etc.

Comment: Also, are you sure that the db connection is actually being established?  If the connection.open() line failed, you might be worried about the wrong piece of code.

Comment: @brianestey the age < 3 was the problem! Thank you so much, rookie mistake.

Comment: Great, glad to help.  You might think about making the age column numeric instead of text, or even storing a birth date.

Comment: Also, beware of SQL Injection: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx

Comment: You might want to use paramtererized queries to avoid string manipulation issues and SQL injection attacks as well.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot one (double) quote in your query string? Specifically before `caregiver2Phone`.

```
string query = "INSERT INTO childdatabase (name2, age, gender, " +
        "adress, caregiver1Name, caregiver1Phone, caregiver2Name, " +      
        "caregiver2Phone) VALUES('" + firstName + "','" + age + 
        "','" + gender + "','" + address + "','" + caregiverOneName + 
        "','" + caregiverOnePhone + "','" + caregiverTwoName + 
        "','" + caregiverTwoPhone + "')";
```

Comment: Are you sure? I can't see, to find where you mean. Mind pointing it out directly?

Comment: He's correct in that your code above is missing a quote, but I don't think your code would actually compile if it was written as shown.

Comment: @Edper, that was my fault. I messed up when editing the line. Check the original source. If a >2k user would like to quickly fix that please do.

Comment: @gunr2171 have you tried to show what's inside ex.Message.ToString()? Like by showing Tracing it thru Debug or simply showing it on your catch using MessageBox.Show().

Comment: Yeah I saw that one courtesy of @brianestey. Good eye Brian!